# Can the Tango timestamp clock be manually reset?

Tags: google-project-tango

I would like to be able to convert the timestamp I get from callbacks to something human readable. Such as I have reached point P at 12:24:54.231. I have noticed that if I restart the tango, the timestamp is seconds since the restart of the tablet. However, if the tablet has been powered on for awhile the time stamp looks very different.

As seconds pass it seems as though the seconds are on the right side of the decimal point.

So my thought was to manually reset the timestamp clock on start-up and record the human time at start up and add the two whenever I need a human readable version of the time.

Is this possible? And if not, what solution could be recommended?

Thanks

Comment: I am not aware of any way of reseting the timestamp clock. What's the reason you want reset it? Why it need to be human readable and correlated to the actual time?

Comment: I wanted to be able to display to the user what time they were at certain points in their journey. So I thought I could use the timestamp in the tango. I assumed there was a Tango way to convert it to time of day. I guess I can just record the current human time during the pose callback.

Comment: In that case, why not just use the system time? I think there might be a way of associating system time and Tango timestamp in each of the application session. To do that, you could try to get a time offset after Tango Service is connected.